# check if class and id exist then change h1 then redirect page after time limit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having some problems getting my JS/JQ to fire in HTML5 page.
Basically I would like to check if the following ID exists and the following class:

> **ID**: page_blog
>
> **CLASS**: page current

```
<section class="page current" id="page_blog" style="z-index: 99; left: -50px;">
...
...
...
```

If they exist then redirect after 2-3 seconds changing the H1 to say

> Loading...

```
<h1><button data-target="home" data-target-activation="click" class="back backwards"></button>Loading...</h1>
```

This is what i have so far:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('li#blogLink.tile').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault(); //will stop the link href to call the blog page

                setTimeout(function () {
                    alert("this has worked");
                    //window.location.href = "http://www.site.co.uk/blog/"; //will redirect to your blog page (an ex: blog.html)
                }, 2000); //will call the function after 2 secs.

            });

        });
</script>
```

I have the following in my page now:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("jquery", "1.7");
    </script>



<script type="text/JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
            if ($(".page.current").length) { // section exists

                $("h1").text("Loading...");
                setTimeout(function () {
                    window.location.href = "http://www.website.co.uk/blog/";
                }, 2000);
        });

</script>
```

But the check to see if the class/id exists isnt firing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('li#blogLink.tile').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($("#page_blog.page.current").length) { // section exists
        $("h1").text("Loading...");
        setTimeout(function() {
            window.location.href = "http://www.site.co.uk/blog/";
        }, 2000);
    }   
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bnWWX/)

Also it's worth mentioning that your selectors are overkill. There should only ever be 1 unique element with the id `#page_blog` and `#blogLink`, so including the tag and classes on the selectors for them is redundant code.

Comment: something wrong with the JS before the 2000.. Thanks for the code.

Comment: missed the curley brace before the comma :P

Comment: I have made the BIGGEST school boy error ever! I didnt embed the jquery library into my page in the header section!

Comment: Rory, added an update. the page doesnt seem to check if the class/id exists. Do i need > 0 on the end?

Comment: never mind, got it working. syntax was wrong on mine.! thanks dude!

Comment: actually still cant get it to check for the id and class... sorry to be a pain.

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work for you, I've added a fiddle to my answer to show how it works.

Comment: Almost as if i need the whole code block on a timer.. but thats will slow my page down!

Comment: i need a delay before the check for #page_blog.page.current is checked. Because the page needs to slide to the HTML5 section and add the class current. I have a feeling its instantly checking for #page_blog.page.current in the home page. So its going to think no need to redirect.

Comment: My HTML5 page needs time to slide to the section block and then add its own "current" class. The problem was my code was instantly checking the home page for 

    #page_blog.page.current

which obviously didnt exist. The workaround is to delay a few seconds then trigger the if statement. Works a treat!

Thank @Rory McCrossan for helping me!